# Learning Java: cannot call a method

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I'm very new to application development, so I hope you guys can teach a thing or two.

I got 1 `JFrame` and 1 `JTextField`. The method I use returns a number everytime I click the button and writes it in the `JTextfield`.

It works! But, the issue is when I want the method to have its own class.

I got this in my method-class:

package newpackage;

```
package test;

public class class1 extends class2 {

    class2 testingobj = null;

    /** this is the constructor. It is given a parameter, so it knows 
     *  about the class2
     */
    public class1(class2 frame) {
        this.testingobj = frame;
    }

    private int num = 0;

    public int testing(){
        if(num <=8){
            num ++;
            testingobj.jTextField1.setText("" +num);
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

And this in my class with `Jbutton` and `JTextField':

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package test;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
public class class2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    class1 testing2ndobj = new class1(this);

    /**
     * Creates new form class2
     */
    public class2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(122, 122, 122)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 199, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(79, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(73, 73, 73)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(173, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
testing2ndobj.testing();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(class2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(class2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(class2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(class2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new class2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    public javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Question 1) I can run the application, but nothing happens when I press the button. Why is that? Is there any golden rule I must remember, when I work across classes?

Thank you!

EDIT: Solved.

Comment: style note: Java classes uses CamelCase naming. Don't use lowercase first letters.

Comment: it's really messy, I'd try but don't want to take the time to read through this novel.

Comment: For starters, in examples you should usually say that `Class2 extends Class1`, not the other way around, and it's rare for `Class2` to both Have-A `Class1` (`testingobj`) and Be-A `Class1` (`extends`). It's hard to tell exactly what you're intending.

Comment: It looks like your `main` method is inside your `actionPerformed` method. Am I missing the closing brace? Please edit your question if it's a typo

Comment: You also took out the relevant parts, and this code won't even compile. You have to attach the event handler (`jButton1ActionPerformed`, probably) to the button somehow, and most likely you're not doing that.

Comment: "It works! But, the issue is when I want the method to have its own class."  Are you sure about the "it works" part? :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are mixing object-oriented and simple module principles here.
I guess, what you primarily intend is have a module (which you have realized as `class1`) and a module, which you have realized as `class2`.

Given that, you are using different mechanisms trying to tie both modules together.
You are using `class1 extends class2` and you are using attributes/fields/variables which are typed as `class1` and `class2`.

Before we continue, please regard the comments for your question: class names in java start with a capital, e.g. `Class2`, or `MyWindow` or `MyFrame` (both of which would be better names than the former).

Now to the inheritance stuff. You have `class2` which extends `JFrame`, which is ok. You want `class2` to be a "Frame" (a window, for that matter).

But you also write `class1` extends `class2`, so `class1` also is a `JFrame`, because `class2` is a `JFrame`. This is not what you intend.

What you do intend, is having a separate module, so you should just declare `class1` (or `MyController` as a better name, again) as

```
public class class1 {
   ...
}
```

without the extends stuff.

Next up, you need to understand, that classes are only the abstract "templates" of the actual "objects". To make a class into a real object, you invoke the constructor (e.g., `new class1()`). The constructor can be seen as a special method which is called with the `new` keyword and which returns a *new* object of the given type (`class1` in this example).

What you need and want is to wire both classes together. Currently, your `main` creates an instance of `class2`, which creates an instance of `class1`, which again creates a (different!) instance of `class2`. In your code, each object only knows about the other object(s), it creates with `new`, but not about the object which have created *this* object.

So `main` knows about the first instance of `class2`. This knows about the instance of `class1`. And that knows about the second instance of `class2` for which it sets the text field. But since the second instance of `class2` ist not visible (because `setVisible()` is only called for the first instance), you don't see anything when pressing the button.

What you should do is implement `class1` as follows:

```
public class class1 extends class2 {

    class2 testingobj = null;

    /** this is the constructor. It is given a parameter, so it knows 
     *  about the class2
     */
    public class1(class2 frame) {
        this.testingobj = frame;
    }

    private int num = 0;

    public int testing(){
        if(num <=8){
            num ++;
            testingobj.jTextField1.setText("" +num);
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

And in your `class2` you should write

```
class1 testing2ndobj = new class1(this);
```

instead of

```
class1 testing2ndobj = new class1();
```

This will give a reference of *this* `class1` to `class2` so that it can access the correct `JTextField`.

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked. Very good explanation and answer. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

I have comment on your code, I do not know if this will help or not.
You are using aggregation for Class1 inside Class2 but in Class1 you made inheritance. You should remove the inheritance if the relation is not inheritance.

Kindly also put in your question the jTextField1 inside class2 to let me able to know how you got it and where you set it before the calling  to the method testing();

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setText` on the wrong instance of `class2`. Here's the call stack that I see:

1. The main method creates a `class2` instance.
2. (I'm assuming you click the button here)
3. The event handler in your `class2` instance creates a `class1` instance
4. The new `class1` instance creates a new `class2` instance (**which is separate** from the instance created by `main`)
5. The main `class2` instance calls `testing()` on the `class1` instance.
6. The `class1` instance calls methods on its internal `class2` instance. This sets the text on the `class2` instance that isn't visible.

If your `testing()` method needs to be in a separate class, yet affect the main `class2` instance, you should pass the `class2` instance to `class1` in the constructor:

```
public class class1 extends class2 {

  // NO! class2 testingobj = new class2();

  private class2 testingobj;
  public class1(class2 dependency) {
    testingobj = dependency;
  }
```